# Cannot selecting first row on database php pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I couldn't understand what is wrong here. I cannot take the first row on database. I also cannot the data which are single according to $ara parameter. Here are the codes:

```
$ara =$_POST['ara'];
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE
                     name like '%".$ara."%' or 
                     surname like '%".$ara."%' or
                     email like '%".$ara."%' 
                    ");
$query->execute(array());           
if ($num_row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    echo "<li><a href='profil.php?id=".$num_row['user_id']."'>" .$num_row['name']. " " .$num_row['surname']."</a></li>";

}else{
    echo "Hiç birşey bulunamadı!";
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your array call:

from

```
$num_row['user_id']
```

To

```
$num_row[0]['user_id']
```

Your code is tested and works, nice job.

what you need to correct is the following line:

```
echo "<li><a href='profil.php?id=" . $num_row[0]['user_id'] . "'>" . $num_row[0]['name'] . " " . $num_row[0]['surname'] . "</a></li>";
```

If you face such problem in the future, it is a good practice to `var_dump` the results like:

```
var_dump($num_row);
```

This will give you a total raw picture of the content.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukÇatalkaya You are welcome, here is my welcome vote-up